# How to hide the navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, uinavigationbar, android-alertdialog, volume

I've got a problem with my Android app (it's my first app).
In few words, when I press the volume up or volume down buttons (and also when an alert comes up) the navigation bar appear and completely mess up the layout.
[NavigationBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhSeF.jpg)

Assuming that I'm using this code to hide the nav bar (it's the immersive mode)

```
 public void FullScreencall(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<19){
        View v =this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        View decorView=getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

(Called in OnCreate)
How can I solve this problem? I just want the nav bar to not appear at all.
Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the IMMERSIVE_STICKY in the onResume or the onFocusChanged.